# Retrieve Heroku Logs for Specific Remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 app that I push to Heroku from Git. I have a staging remote and a production remote on Heroku. When I run:

```
$ heroku logs
```

I get the staging logs. How can I get the production logs?

```
$ git remote -v
origin some/github/path (fetch)
origin some/github/path (push)
staging git@heroku.com:some-heroku-app.git (fetch)
staging git@heroku.com:some-heroku-app.git (push)
production git@heroku.com:some-other-heroku-app.git (fetch)
production git@heroku.com:some-other-heroku-app.git (push)
```

Attempts include:

```
$ heroku logs -s staging
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace -s with -r.  `heroku logs -r staging` (or production or whatever).

Comment: Nice and easy to remember. The 'r' stands for remote?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Heroku app name

```
heroku logs --app my-production-app
```